# Firestore rule does not work trying to list collection when trying to read resource.data values

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Simple scenario:

- I have a collection named "foo"
- It has a single document with the ID of "bar"
- "bar" has a single string field named "sample" with the value "fail"

If I try something like this in my ruleset:

```
  service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
      // Test rule
      match /foo/{id} {
        allow read: if resource.data.sample == 'fail';
      }
    }
  }
```

It is able to query on "bar" when I specify the document ID in the query, but if I try to list all items the query comes back with "Missing or insufficient permissions.".  I also tried `allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/foo/$(id)).data.sample == 'fail';` and I get the same results.

There's only a single record in the collection, I'm able to query on it individually when I reference the data ID.  I understand that for a query work properly, the filter conditions need to match the rules.  In this case, I'm not applying any filter, but all (1) records should be returned.

I'm having a hard time trying to find solutions on this.  All the solutions I've seen say that the query results need to match the rules, and they should match in this case.

Comment: To be complete here, can edit the question to show the client code that doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: It's working fine today, and I didn't change anything.  Really weird.  In any case, I'll close it out.

Comment: @GeekLad did you ever determine the root cause?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what was going on, but it appears to be working now.  I didn't change anything to make it work.  The test code I was using was very simple via the web API:

```
function test() { firebase.firestore().collection("foo").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
    }); });} test();
```